# jQuery 'this' for elements children

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

Im just getting to grips with jquery and im trying to write something like this, please note the puesdo code on the 3rd line.

How can i write `this` (as in the `.tile`) and then select the `tiles` box element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tile').hover(function () {
        $('this->.box').stop().slideToggle("300");
    });     
});
```

Ive made a jsfiddle of the problem here - http://jsfiddle.net/pudle/m6ZjH/2/

Comment: Google search [jquery children](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+children)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tile').hover(function () {
        $(this).children('.box').stop().slideToggle("300");
    });     
});
```

Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6ZjH/3/) updated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan nice =) Haven't seen that used often but nicely works! (A selector with `this` that is)